# how to send parameters to an ejs page from node js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am passing the title to the EJS pages from node js as below

```
router.get('/Home', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('Pages/Home', { title: 'Home' });
});
```

Can I pass a second parameter along with this as..?

```
router.get('/Home', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('Pages/Home', { title: 'Home' },{ role: 'Admin' });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can but you need to wrap all your needed parameters in one object like so:

```
router.get('/Home', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('Pages/Home', { title: 'Home', role: 'Admin' });
});
```